# White little screen on the top left corner when I'm installing ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I want to install Ubuntu 14 next to Windows 8.1. I have BIOS and fat32 file system on my flash drive where is an ubuntu installation wizard. But after I enter "install Ubuntu" it just shows white square(approximately a quarter of the screen) on the top-left of the screen. 
What do I need to do?
Thanks everybody for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess right, you should not see the desktop? You can turn off the installation window, adjust the desktop resolution is set inside. After entering the installation program from the menu on it.

Comment: no, I just clicked install Ubuntu and there is a black screen with the white square on top left. Thats it

Comment: You can provide a picture?